# GitHub for website development

Tags: github

OK< I know I can use Eclipse for Java programming and such but I work using WAMP for editing PHP, XHTML, JavaScript files... what IDE is best to edit the files and use GitHub? Because I don't know want to go to localhost and then copy my files to my local GitHub repo...

Comment: Are you asking what IDE has good git integration?  Is the answer going to depend on whether you're using GitHub or any other git repository?

Comment: The question is not clear to me: do you want to remotely (ssh) edit your file and be able to push your files from your remote to github, right?

Comment: Yes, Renaud, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

[Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) might be what you are looking for! It's an online IDE with out-of-the-box intergration with GitHub, heroku etc. and gives you the ability to share workspaces as well.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has the egit plugin that is really nice. You can use aptana which is based around eclipse but includes all the web views. It can basically edit everything you mentioned and really well, while providing a nice wrapper for your git repos

http://aptana.org/products/studio3

http://eclipse.org/egit/

Answer (score 0):

Emacs + tramp + the command line ?

*Update:* [magit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Magit) is reported to support tramp

*Update:*

My experience: I have a distant linux server running a rails app. and private git repositories / apache (using several VirtualHosts with or without ssl). That server runs a ssh server. I use bare ssh session for command line usage (git, nominal admin.) and emacs + tramp to remotely edit the files presents on that server. I you are not rebuked by anti-eye candies tools (as for not-at-all drag'n'drop stuff), I would suggest you to give emacs a try (see [EmacsW32](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) and [nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) if you are under Windows). I assume you can install a ssh server on your WAMP machine… If this is the case, you could open your file from emacs just by using the following syntax (assuming you would edit the /home/renaud/.bashrc on the distant server):

```
/ssh:user@obf.uscatedmachine.org:/home/user/.bashrc
```

With putty on windows: see [that](http://wm-eddie.info/2008/11/29/visiting-files-using-ssh-in-emacsw32/) and [this](http://wiki.vpslink.com/HOWTO%3a_Edit_Files_Remotely_with_Emacs) posts.

It works the same for directories. You shall be prompted for your password once, and then edit the file/directory as if it is just on your machine. For the git part, I have verified myself since I do the git stuff directly from a ssh terminal, but latest [magit](http://magit.github.com/magit/)
 is reported to support tramp (*i.e.* remote git plumbering from my understanding).

If you have never used emacs before, it will not be easy. You will have to learn emacs basics first and customize it to fit you needs. My opinion is that's worth to give it a try. I could help you with basic configuration if needed.

(I use myself emacs almost for everything on my linux box from simple text editing to Java programming.)

*Update:*

After some testing, magit works very well remotely (tested on linux)! A new mode added to my configuration thanks to your question!

Answer (score 0):

well is not an IDE but vim with some git plugins is the best for me.
Eclipse should have some git plugins also, I think.
The best way to learn git is yo use it from command line!